# MOSS 2016 (EE): PowerShell add column description not work!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Help! I need somebody, help! Not just anybody, Help! :'(

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
$VrbWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://sps_site.loc"
$VrbList = $VrbWeb.Lists["sps_list"]

$VrbFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::URL
$VrbFieldName = $VrbList.Fields.Add("Column Name","URL", $false) 
$VrbNewField  = $VrbList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName($VrbFieldName)
$VrbNewField.DisplayFormat = "Image"  
$VrbNewField.Description = "Text22" #NOT WORK!
$VrbNewField.Update()
```

**How to add a description to a column?**

Answer (score 3):

DisplayFormat cannot be "Image" as a string.

PowerShell example:

```
$VrbNewField.DisplayFormat = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUrlFormatTypes]::Image;
```

By the way, this works just fine:

```
$list = $web.lists["TestList"]
$list.Fields["TestUrl"].Description = "Test description"
$list.Fields["TestUrl"].Update()
```